# Asciidoc archetype for Hugo

Tags: hugo, asciidoc

I just started to use [Hugo](http://gohugo.io) and I want to use it with Asciidoc.

The default "archetype" (i.e. template) is in markdown (*default.md*). Anyone knows how to get an archetype for Asciidoc?

In particular, shall I rename to *default.adoc*?

This is how the default archetype looks like.

***default.md***

```
---
title: "{{ replace .TranslationBaseName "-" " " | title }}"
date: {{ .Date }}
draft: true
---
```

Comment: Are you using a Hugo external helper like asciidoctor?

Comment: Yes, I do. But actually this question does not make sense. I can't downvote my own question. So bad!

Comment: Or you could improve the question, by editing it, to describe your question more clearly. It might help others who are going through the same thought process. You could also delete the question, but from what I have read that isn't something to be done too often.

Comment: Yep. Slightly improved the question. Anyway, doesn't matter much. This question is in the abyss of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shall be kept as `default.md`.

This only represents the font-matter that will be on top of the files and is not linked to any type (i.e. *MarkDown* or *AsciiDoc*, it will be the same).